# Counting values in SQL with conditional logic / multiple criteria

Tags: sql, count

I have a table that contains several thousand products with the following columns:

- `scores`: includes the quality of a score from 1-100
- `y_2018`: the product was in service during 2018
- `y_2020`: the product was in service during 2020
- `y_2021`: the product was in service during 2021

My objective is to categorize products by the different years that they have been in service. This would mean there would be a "1/3" column for products in service only in 2018, only in 2020, and only in 2021. There would also be a "2/3" column for products in service in 2018 and 2020 but not 2021, 2018 and 2021 but not 2020, and 2020 and 2021 but not 2018. Lastly there would be a "3/3" column for the products that have been in service for 2018, 2020, and 2021. This is the code I have thusfar:

```
SELECT 
case
when (case scores)>=0 and scores<30 then '0-30'
when (case scores)>=30 and scores<70 then '30-70'
when (case scores)>=70 and scores<100 then '70-100'
ELSE NULL end as "Score Range"
,COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 IS NULL AND y_2021 IS 
NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ 
COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NULL AND y_2020 
IS NOT NULL AND y_2021 IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+
COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NULL AND y_2020 
IS NULL AND y_2021 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "1/3"
,COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 IS NOT NULL AND y_2021 IS 
NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ 
COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NULL AND y_2020 
IS NOT NULL AND y_2021 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+
COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 
IS NULL AND y_2021 IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "2/3"
,COUNT(CASE WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 IS NOT NULL AND y_2021 IS 
NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "3/3"
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I think I'm close and my current output looks like this:

```
Score Range  |  1/3    2/3   3/3
70-100       |  2000   2000   500
30-70        |  1000   1000   300
0-30         |  1500   1500   400
```

The main question I have is why the "1/3" and "2/3" are the same and how can I adjust my query to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: You said no double counting. Does that mean that the product that show up in all three years category should not show up in 2020 & 2021 category and only 2021 category?

Comment: Yes that's correct. So none of the products that show up in the only 2021 category should show up in the 2020 and 2021 category. None of the products in either the 2021 category or the 2020 and 2021 category should show up in the all three years category.

Comment: I am talking about the opposite way. What if the product was valid in all three years? Then it would show up in all three categories only 2021, 2020 & 2021, all 3. This way the product will be counted thrice. Is this okay?

Comment: If a product was valid in all 3 years it should only show up in a 2018/2020/2021 column | if a product was valid in 2020 and 2021 but not in 2018 it should show up in a 2020 and 2021 column. If a product was only valid in 2021 it should show up in a 2021 column.

Comment: Note according to your logic your ranges should be  0-29/30-69/70-99

Comment: Alright I think my initial criteria was a little 2 strict, I edited the question and posted a query that I think is closer. My apologies for the adjustment and thank you for your answers that have helped me clarify.

Comment: What does the column y_2018 , y_2020 and y_2021 contains when they are NOT NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding this correctly, but if you want a column for each year they were in service, you can just repeat your existing count with minimal editing.

```
,COUNT(CASE
   WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL and y_2020 IS NULL and y_2021 IS NULL THEN 1
   WHEN y_2018 IS NULL and y_2020 IS NOT NULL and y_2021 IS NULL THEN 1
   WHEN y_2018 IS NULL and y_2020 IS NULL and y_2021 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
   ELSE NULL END) AS "COUNT 1/3"
,COUNT(CASE
   WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL and y_2020 IS NOT NULL and y_2021 IS NULL THEN 1
   WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL and y_2020 IS NULL and y_2021 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
   WHEN y_2018 IS NULL and y_2020 IS NOT NULL and y_2021 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
   ELSE NULL END) AS "COUNT 2/3"
,COUNT(CASE
   WHEN y_2018 IS NOT NULL and y_2020 IS NOT NULL and y_2021 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
ELSE NULL END) AS "COUNT 3/3"
```

edit: to add multiple 'when' conditions per grouping

Comment: While this gets me closer it doesn't solve the double counting issue: there were some products in service during 2018, 2020, and 2021. Some in service in 2020 and 2021 but not 2018. This just gets the raw counts of the products that were in service during a time.

Comment: I had missed that you wanted to identify those groupings, and so adding `and` statements to a `case when` allows you to be more granular. I've updated my answer to reflect

Comment: Alright I think my initial criteria was a little 2 strict, I edited the question and posted a query that I think is closer. My apologies for the adjustment and thank you for your answers that have helped me clarify.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, it looks like what you were missing is that each `case` statement can have multiple `when`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make three different columns with three different conditions like below:

```
SELECT 
case
when (case scores)>=0 and scores<30 then '0-30'
when (case scores)>=30 and scores<70 then '30-70'
when (case scores)>=70 and scores<100 then '70-100'
ELSE NULL end as "Score Range"
,SUM(CASE WHEN y_2021 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 IS NULL AND y_2018 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "y_2021_COUNT"
,SUM(CASE WHEN y_2021 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 IS NOT NULL AND y_2018 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "y_2021_2020_COUNT"
,SUM(CASE WHEN y_2021 IS NOT NULL AND y_2020 IS NOT NULL AND y_2018 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "y_2021_2020_2018_COUNT"
FROM table
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Alright I think my initial criteria was a little 2 strict, I edited the question and posted a query that I think is closer. My apologies for the adjustment and thank you for your answers that have helped me clarify.